# Custom NavigationBar with synchronous UISwitch

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar

I have a a story board with View Controllers that are wrapped in a nav bar controller. I have a UI switch on a few of the nav bars as the right side "button". I'd like the value of the `UISwitch` to be synchronous throughout the application, meaning if the `UISwitch` is on in one view, it should be on in the other.

[image]

I'm trying to do so by creating a custom NavBar class, and implementing it in IB. I'm not too sure how I could do it. I tried setting the `UINavBar` in the Interface Builder's `NavigationController`, but I can't seem to connect the instance in the navBar class to IB.

[image]

The following is the header code for "BVYNavigationBar", where I try to make the connection for the `UISwitch` into IB:

```
@interface BVYNavigationBar : UINavigationBar

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwitch *controlSwitch;

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it programmatically, like so:

```
@implementation BVYNavigationBar

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];
    UISwitch *switchButton = [[UISwitch alloc] init];
    CGRect frame = switchButton.frame;
    frame.origin.x += 250;
    frame.origin.y += 10;
    switchButton.frame = frame;
    [self addSubview:switchButton];
}

@end
```